# Angular post gives back weird data

Tags: http, post, angular, response

Im doing this:

```
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Encoding': 'deflate'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({
        "password": password,
        "username": username
    });
    return this.http.post('URL HERE', body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.text());
```

but it returns something like this:

```
 ��V���0���C�`Y�F��Z��J��2�%n�l�f[��k�- I�f�M}�F̘y3o<�������J��-SYV�]�#i�,[���T���3�?�/fv��V$��ʈl�Ŀ��2?<�'B5� V��`��&kA !�F݌C�VJ�㍻�,/�+�fKw�S���%�Ѓ|�QJ>}�9�7fz���9zL�M�Gt�!�#?:�6��?�fH�k̄���Q(����z�7��U�r2�7��g2�[�
```

When I do the call from Postman, no issues.

Any tips ?

Comment: What does `res.json()` instead of `res.text()` return?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0(…)

Comment: What does the server send? Looks like binary. AFAIK currently only JSON is supported.

Comment: It does return JSON. Another call from the server works fine.

Comment: Maybe invalid JSON? Otherwise I think it should work with `res.json()`

Comment: @FalkoWoudstra check your URL , I had got this error when I was using invalid url in `post` call.

Comment: URL works. Just tested in Postman. Can it be a problem with gzipped content ?

Comment: which version of angular you are using? is it rc4?

Comment: Angular2. Not sure what rc4 is..

Answer (score 1):

this.http.post('URL HERE', body, headers) should have been this.http.post('URL HERE', body, options)

## stupidme